# Compatibility between Telerik ASP.Net controls and MS AntiXSS library

Tags: asp.net, telerik, antixsslibrary

My questions are hypothetical, but hope I am giving all the info needed to answer them.

1. Are there any known compatibility issues when using Telerik ASP.Net controls and Microsoft Anti XSS library?
2. Will the usage of telerik controls affect the WCAG compliance in any way?

Comment: Which version of the Anti-XSS library are you referring?

Comment: I am using the latest version of Anti-XSS library, version 4.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have not worked with MS Anti XSS before, but if it works flawlessly with the MS AJAX Toolkit, it should work with the telerik Ajax controls, too. With regards to the WCAG compliance, I know a page on the telerik site which presents what level of compliance their controls support - view it here: http://www.telerik.com/products/aspnet-ajax/getting-started/tech-sheets-overview/accessibility-support.aspx

Comment: Thanks for link to the WCAG compliance of Telerik controls, but I would need a definite answer on the compatibility with MS Anti XSS. I have tried searching the web for answers for the same but was not able to find a definitive answer

Answer (score 0):

Unless Telerik is using AntiXSS, which seems doubtful, otherwise it would be distributed with it, it's not going to have any effect. If you're swapping out the default encoding using the various hacks around there, or the beta of 4.1 that may affect it, but without viewing the Telerik source there's no way to tell.